# Password reset confirm not work in Rest-Auth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I use `rest-auth` for backend with django rest framework.

**In urls:**

```
path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls'))-at
```

when I access to `http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/password/reset/` I get an email field. After providing email, I get `NoReverseMatch at /rest-auth/password/reset/`. Mainly, **Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

How can I fix this??

**I tried in urls:**

```
    from rest_auth.views import PasswordResetConfirmView

    url(r'^rest-auth/password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
    name='password_reset_confirm')
```

Now I get an email and when I go to the link I get four field **(New password1, New password2, Uid, Token)** but **(Uid and Token field are empty)**.

How can I get this 2 field **(Uid and Token)** filled with url's Uid and Token??

Comment: If you are using front-end like React, an example would be [React example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769136/django-rest-auth-reset-password-uid-and-token). As written in the urls.py, you have to retrieve the parameters of **uid** and **token** from the url